# Confusion related to derivation of soft thresholding function

Tags: optimization, lasso

I was going through this [paper](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~pradeepr/paperz/invcov.pdf) and reading some problem(lasso type) that was being solved using soft thresholding, but I didn't get how it was derived. Can anyone please provide some suggestions?

I didn't get how

$\mu = -c +S(c-b/a,\lambda/a)$

$f(\mu) = \frac{1}{2}a\mu^2 + b\mu + \lambda|c+\mu|)$\

$\underset{\mu}{\operatorname{argmin}} f(\mu)$ = $\underset{\mu}
{\operatorname{argmin}} {\; \mu^2 + 2*b/a\mu + 2*\lambda/a|c+\mu|}$\

If $\mu$ is not equal to 0
Taking the derivative wrt $\mu$ and equating to 0 we get\
\newline

$2\mu + 2b/a + 2\lambda/a*sign(u) = 0$\

or, $\mu = -b/a - \lambda/a*sign(\mu)$\

If $\mu$ > 0\

$\mu = -b/a - \lambda/a$\

Since c is a positive quantity, $c -b/a-\lambda/a$ > 0 and using the thresholding operator in the paper  as \
$\mu = -c + S(c-b/a,\lambda/a)$\

S(z,r) = sign(z) max{|z|-r,0}  I can get $\mu = -b/a-lambda/a$\

Now if $\mu < 0$, I get

$\mu = -b/a + \lambda/a$

I am confused how to obtain this condition from the thresholding operator given in the paper. Also the condition when $\mu$ = 0

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of $|\mu + c|$ is $sgn(\mu + c)$ for $\mu + c \neq 0$.

Comment: An answer needs a little more explanation. Could you expand on this a bit more?

Comment: Correct that step and see if that leads to a resolution of the question.